# Transitive import error: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '...'

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import, pytest

I'm confused now.  Here is the project tree:

```
project
- source
- - lib
- - - __init__.py
- - - utils.py
- - - stats.py
- test
- - lib
- - - test_stats.py
```

`stats.py` has `import utils`, which indeed works if one executes `stats.py` itself.  Now `test_stats.py` has `import lib.stats` but that results in the `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'utils'` error if executed as `PYTHONPATH=source pytest` in the `project` directory:

```
==================================== ERRORS ====================================
___________________ ERROR collecting test/lib/test_stats.py ___________________
ImportError while importing test module '/lib/test_stats.py'.
Hint: make sure your test modules/packages have valid Python names.
Traceback:
test/lib/test_stats.py:40: in <module>
    import lib.stats
source/lib/__init__.py:42: in <module>
    from .stats import Stats
source/lib/stats.py:40: in <module>
    import utils
E   ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'utils'
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! Interrupted: 1 errors during collection !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
=========================== 1 error in 0.19 seconds ============================
```

What's going on and how to properly execute tests with such directory structure?

**P.S.**  I'm aware of (development mode) `pip install ...` and `tox` tricks (for module search path), but I would like to understand whether they are absolutely necessary to get this going or I already assume something wrong in this simple setup.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`import utils` in Python 3 is absolute import, Python looks module `utils` in `sys.path`.

When you run `stats.py` as a script Python adds the directory `project/source/lib/` to `sys.path`. So `import utils` in the script works.

But when you run `test_stats.py` Python doesn't add `project/source/lib/` to `sys.path`. So `import utils` doesn't work.

A way to overcome that is to use relative import: `from . import utils`. In `stats.py` it means: do not search `sys.path`, import module `utils` from the same directory as `stats.py`. But then you loose ability to run `stats.py` as a script. So move main code from `stats.py` to a separate script outside of `lib/`.

A slightly different solution is to move main code from `stats.py` to module `__main__.py` and execute the module using `python -m lib` (`project/source/` must be in `sys.path`).

Comment: Thanks for this information; very useful.  I actually don't intend to make `stats.py` executable, this was just for the purposes of demonstration.  Nevertheless, I have to ask you, what is actually considered "best practice" in such cases with respect to library development?  Do people generally do `from . import utils` then?

Comment: Looking at `numpy` ([fromnumeric.py](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/v1.13.0/numpy/core/fromnumeric.py)), the `from . import ...` style seems to be preferred.

Comment: That's highly debatable question. For stdlib PEP8 recommends absolute import (in your case it's `from lib import utils`). I know projects that also demand absolute import. Personally I prefer relative import.