# Circular import issue

Tags: python, import, setuptools

Pretty sure similar questions have been asked a lot of times, but I struggle to find them. Anyways, there is a certain project that looks this:

```
├── fin
│   ├── rss_reader
│   │   ├── cfg.py
│   │   ├── rss_reader.py
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   └── setup.py
│   └── ....
```

Both `setup.py` and `rss_reader.py` import `cfg.py`. Since `setup.py` actually exists, the project is meant to be distributed. So, when there is `import cfg` is used in `rss_reader.py`, the project works just fine when called directly without installation but doesn't work (as expected) when installed and called via a command defined in `setup.py`. However, it's the other way around when `from rss_reader import cfg` is used: the script works just fine when installed and after a direct call `ImportError` occurs:

`ImportError: cannot import name 'cfg' from partially initialized module 'rss_reader' (most likely due to a circular import) (/home/twat/fin/rss_reader/rss_reader.py)`

How do you make it work as intended in both cases?

Comment: The `setup.py` file must not import the library code.  Remove that.  For your circular import issue, you'll need to add enough details for a [mcve].

Comment: Food for thought: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49454605/7976758 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/55080665/7976758